# BigQuery - Combine Values for a Record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i'm attempting to combine the number of items that an individual has purchased into 1 line so i can run a basket analysis of sorts in BigQuery. Here is what my data looks like:

```
Name       Date_Processed       Items.SKU
John       Feb-1                ABC123
                                ABC245
                                CST099
Sarah      Feb 3                ABC245
                                CST099
                                CST099
                                CZT011
Emily      Feb 3                ABC123
```

As you can see, each purchaser has 1 main line in the data and then a line for each item purchased. Here's what I have now, but can't figure out how to combine or concatenate the data:

```
SELECT name, date, ARRAY(SELECT sku FROM UNNEST(line_items) AS itemSKU ORDER BY sku asc)

FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS instance
  FROM `shopify.orders`
) orders -- identify duplicate rows

WHERE instance = 1
AND
date(date_processed) BETWEEN date_sub(current_date(), interval 30 day) AND current_date
```

Is there anything I can do in BigQuery to get this data to look like this:

```
Name       Date_Processed       Items.SKU
John       Feb-1                ABC123,ABC245,CST099
Sarah      Feb 3                ABC245,CST099,CST099,CZT011
Emily      Feb 3                ABC123
```

I was thinking about using the ARRAY_CONCAT, but can't get this to work.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So if those are really rows in the database then you cannot combine them (unless there are other columns).  I will note that in BigQuery, you would see a similar layout if Items were arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, date, 
  (SELECT SRING_AGG(sku ORDER BY sku) FROM UNNEST(line_items)) AS skus
FROM `shopify.orders`
```

or a little/tiny less verbose

```
SELECT name, date, 
  (SELECT SRING_AGG(sku ORDER BY sku) FROM t.line_items) AS skus
FROM `shopify.orders` t
```

Comment: this is spot on! worked like a charm. the string_agg works perfectly. i will accept this as soon as i can.